# Intersection in Python List

Tags: python, list, intersection

I'm newbie on Python. I have this list:

```
a = [[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7,8,9], ...]
b = [[0,6,9],[1,5], ...]
```

a & b can have more components, depends on data. I want to know is there any intersection on these lists? If there's any intersection, I wanna have a result like this:

```
c = [[6,9], ...]
```

Comment: Intersection is an operation between two sets. You have two lists of lists, so I'm having a hard time figuring out what it is you're asking for with just the one example.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the expected outcome? `c` contains `[6,9]`, but apparently not `[1]` which would be the intersection of a[0] and b[1].

Comment: I'm working on spatio-temporal clustering using ST-DBSCAN. I want to modify the neighborhoods within eps1 and eps2. Eps1 for the spatial limit distance and eps2 for the temporal. I need to find the intersection of neighborhoods within eps1 and eps2. (I'm sorry, not really good in English)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't asking for your use case (please excuse that I will not read up on the background of ST-DBSCAN) but a mathematical precise description of the function f that results in c=f(a,b) depending on the values of a and b. For example if my use case was to calculate the average height of the buildings in a city, then f would be f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=(x_1+x_2+...+x_n)/n.

Comment: My question is : Is there any elements in list a intersect with list b. For example, [0,1,2,3] in list a will find intersection in list b which is [0,6,9] and [1,5]. [4,5,6,7,8,9] in list a will find intersection in list b which is [0,6,9] and [1,5]. There's an intersection between [4,5,6,7,8,9] and [0,6,9], so the result will be [6,9]

Comment: Are you looking for this: f({A_1,…,A_n},{B_1,…,B_m})={A_1∩B_1,A_1∩B_2,…,A_1∩B_m,A_2∩B_1,A_2∩B_2,…,A_2∩B_m,…A_n∩B_1,A_n∩B_2,…,A_n∩B_m} ? If so then Abram has the right answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that intersection is an operation between two sets, and you have given two lists of lists, it's very unclear what you're looking for. Do you want the intersection of a[1] and b[0]? Do you want the intersection of every possible combination?

I'm guessing you want the intersection of every combination of two sets between your two lists, which would be:

```
from itertools import product
[set(x).intersection(set(y)) for x, y in product(a, b)]
```

Comment: You might want to filter out empty sets: `[set(x).intersection(set(y)) for x, y in product(a, b) if len(set(x).intersection(set(y)))>0]`

Answer (score 2):

The `set` type, built into Python, supports intersection natively. However, note that `set` can only hold one of each element (like a mathematical set). If you want to hold more than one of each element, try `collections.Counter`.

You can make `set`s using `{}` notation (like dictionaries, but without values):

```
>>> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>>> b = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}
```

and you can intersect them using the `&` operator:

```
>>> print a & b
set([2, 4])
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in your example code this is not a tuple, it's a list (the original question asked about lists, but references tuples in the example code).

To get an intersection of two tuples or lists, use a code like this:

```
set((1,2,3,4,5)).intersection(set((1,2,3,7,8)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In one line:

```
common_set = set([e for r in a for e in r])&set([e for r in b for e in r])
```

Or easier:

```
common_set = set(sum(a,[])) & set(sum(b,[]))
```

Common will be a set. You can easily convert set to the list is you need it:

```
common_list = list(common_set)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it... assuming you want the intersection of the flatten list.

```
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> a = [[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7,8,9]]
>>> b = [[0,6,9],[1,5]]

>>> list(set(chain(*a)).intersection(set(chain(*b))))
[0, 9, 5, 6, 1]
```

Comment: It's not the answer, but close with it (I guess). Can we check manually one by one? [0,6,9] with [0,1,2,3], [4,5,6,7,8,9], and so on. [1,5] with [0,1,2,3], [4,5,6,7,8,9], and so on.