# comparing list with other list, not looking for "in" "=" or "re.search"

Tags: python-3.6

I do have two file which contains domains, after reading it with readlines(), I am getting two lists:
a = ['abc.com','cde.com','efg.com']
b = ['yabc.com','cde.com','abce.com','efg.com']

Now I need to find the common between the two.

1. No partial match allowed.( abc.com above has two partial match )
2. There is no order

Output should be : [''cde.com,'efg.com']
There is one problem I am handling manually, in some line of files we have multiple domain with "|" separator like:
abc.com|cde.com|efg.com which is treated as one string in and giving me list like:
['abc.com|cde.com|efg.com\n','xyz.com']
In this case again abc, cde and efg.com would be missed.

I tried set, intersection, two for loops, re.search, but not accurate result.

Comment: Try to clean up your data before processing. If you have lists like  ['abc.com|cde.com|efg.com\n','xyz.com'], you should first convert them to  ['abc.com','cde.com','efg.com\n','xyz.com']

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intersection in Python List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948378/intersection-in-python-list)